# Regex pattern for removing .0 from a string containing date separated by Delimiter

Tags: java, regex, date

I have a string which looks something like this:

```
"2013-10-19 22:21:21#2013-10-23 16:17:19#2013-10-25 13:15:14.0#2013-10-19 08:11:34.0#2013-10-23 16:17:19#"
```

I need to remove the .0 from the end of the date.
i.e. `2013-10-25 13:15:14.0 should be 2013-10-25 13:15:14`

What can be the possible regex pattern for this..

Comment: You should post your attempts next time.

Comment: I should and I do..But this time I had no clue how to approach...Hence avoided posting..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is your string and there's no other data inside, you can use a simple replace; no need for any regex:

```
String str = "2013-10-19 22:21:21#2013-10-23 16:17:19#2013-10-25 13:15:14.0#2013-10-19 08:11:34.0#2013-10-23 16:17:19#";
String res = str.replace(".0", "");
System.out.println(res);
```

Output:

```
2013-10-19 22:21:21#2013-10-23 16:17:19#2013-10-25 13:15:14#2013-10-19 08:11:34#2013-10-23 16:17:19# - See more at: http://ideone.com/WrDbqS#sthash.iQsWV8gp.dpuf
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/WrDbqS)

Comment: Bingo..It was that simple..Never thought..!!.I went into Regex mode and things started getting out of control..This could have been solved by using simple string function...Oops..!!

Comment: @AngelsandDemons It can happen to the best of us, don't worry :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\.0(?=#)", "");
```

This will replace `.0` with an empty string if it is followed by a `#`

Comment: Hello..Thanks..However this works provided I have a # to end the string..Without hash as expected this does not work

Comment: Correct but your example always has `#` after `.0` and just simply replacing `.0` can be risky sometimes as it may make a number `25.05` to `25.5`

Comment: Agreed.But my string may/may not have # everytime..Its a delimiter actually.So for just 1 entry it won't be present.

Answer (score 0):

This removes (by replacing with blank) `.0` when appearing before `#` or end of the string:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\.0(?=#|$)", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\.\\d+", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `regex` you can do as follows.

```
 String str="2013-10-19 22:21:21#2013-10-23 16:17:19#2013-10-25 13:15:14.0#2013-10-19 08:11:34.0#2013-10-23 16:17:19#";
   String[] dates=str.split("#");
   for(String i:dates){
       if(i.lastIndexOf('0')==(i.length()-1)){
           System.out.println(i.replaceAll(".0",""));
       }else {
           System.out.println(i);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Specifically asked for Regex or something similar...Loop usage is not preferred.